# How to display thumbnails in a random order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I found a code to display xml data in to the bootstrap thumbnail. I added a JavaScript code for random that all thumbnails. When the page refresh, need to show that thumbnails randomly. But my code is not working. How can I fix the issue?

Here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: showCD
  });
});

function showCD(xml) {
  xml = $(xml).children();
  let i = 0;

  $(xml).children().each(function() {
    let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
    let ARTIST = $(this).find("ARTIST").text();
    let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
    let COMPANY = $(this).find("COMPANY").text();

    let html = `<div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail" id="random">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

    i++;

    if (i <= 3) {
      $("#xmldata").append(html);
      $("#xmldataall").append(html);
    } else {
      $("#other").append(html);
    }

  });
}

$(function() {
 $("#random").html($("#random").children().sort(function() { return 0.5 -    Math.random() }));
});    }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>


<input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton1" class="reveal" style="float: right;" onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

<div id="toggle_container" class='hide'>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="row" id="other"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/mE9TTWknILVAu3YY?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` function won't affect the DOM order of elements, it only sorts the list of items returned by jQuery.

What you can do instead is modify your code as follows:

```
function showCD(xml){
    var items = $(xml).children().children();
    items.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });

    let i = 0;

    items.each(function () {                    
        let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        let ARTIST =$(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
        let COMPANY =$(this).find("COMPANY").text();

        let html = `<div class="col-md-4" id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

        i++;

        if(i <= 3)    {
            $("#xmldata").append(html);
            $("#xmldataall").append(html);
        }
        else{            
            $("#other").append(html);
        }

    });
}
```

And remove this part:

```
$("#random").html($("#random").children().sort(function() { return 0.5 -    Math.random() }));
```

Comment: also you don't need to declare `i` outside the `each` loop. The callback can take two arguments: the index and the current item. From the jQuery docs:
`$.each( [ "a", "b", "c" ], function( i, l ){
  alert( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
});`